# access other object's properties in javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, binding

In a JavaScript function, belonging to an javascript object, I'd like to use a value of another object's property:

```
var firstObject={
    says:"something"
}

var secondObject={
    speak:function(){console.log(this.saysToo)},
    saysToo:firstObject.says
}

secondObject.speak();
```

In my inspecting "secondObject" in a debugger, the "saysToo" has the correct value. However, if I try to access it via "this.saysToo" it is undefined.

How can I access the first object's  property from within my second object?

Comment: I'm not getting undefined. What browser you using? Also, please post output.

Comment: [Works for me.](http://jsfiddle.net/csBXN/)

Comment: Is this your real, actual code?

Comment: sorry, you are right. Stems from a false simplification of the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both `firstObject` and `secondObject` are separate objects. The keyword `this` refers to its execution context's object.

```
<script>
var firstObject = {
    says: "something",
    test: function() {
        //this == firstObject
        console.log(this == firstObject); //shows: true
    }
}

var secondObject = {
    speak: function() {
        //this == secondObject
        console.log(this.saysToo);
    },
    saysToo: firstObject.says,
    test: function() {
        //this == secondObject
        console.log(this == secondObject); //shows: true
        console.log(this == firstObject); //shows: false
    },
}

secondObject.speak();

//this == window
console.log(this===window); //shows: true

console.log(typeof this.saysToo); //shows: undefined
//because "this.saysToo" is same as "window.saysToo" in this (global) context
</script>
```

A function call can be bound with other object using `call` of `apply` method to make `this` in that function behave as another object.

```
<script>
var firstObject = {
    says: "something",
    saysToo: "other"
}

var secondObject = {
    speak: function() {
        console.log(this.saysToo);
    },
    saysToo: firstObject.says
}

secondObject.speak(); //shows: "something"

//bind with "firstObject"
secondObject.speak.call(firstObject); //shows: "other"
</script>
```